# Flex dashboard component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dashboard

I are looking to use a **dashboard** component in flex/as3 product.

So far I found this :http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Dashboard

I would like to know if anyone used such a product and can provide input on it.

Our base (flexible) requirements are:

Ability to move , resize , show - hide arrange windows inside the dashboard, something similar to flash builder editor.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashboard application is inspired from the sample Dashboard application developed by the Adobe Flex  community.
I suggest you to get the source of Adobe Dashboard Flex project and run it on your Flash builder.
It's more pretty and clean than any other imitation.

1- go to this link to download the project source as FXP (flash pro project) :
   http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/flex/Dashboard-Part4-End.zip

2- Unzip the "Dashboard-Part4-End.fxp" file.

3- import it on your FB like this: File > Import Flash Builder Project > File  and browse to your "Dashboard-Part4-End.fxp" file.

4- That's all, Run the project and look how it's pretty and clean : you can resize, move and reorder widgets with animation  (see attached screenshot).

[image]